# Android Pass Variable To Included View

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout as such:

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.myPackage.MyViewModel" />
    </data>


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
      <include layout="@layout/modal_popup_view" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

How can I pass the variable `viewModel` into the included layout?

Answer (score 1):

Define a `viewModel` (or any other named) variable in your `@layout/modal_popup_view`.

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.myPackage.PopupViewModel" />
</data>
```

In `MyViewModel`, expose the property `popupViewModel` of the type `PopupViewModel`. Pass the property to the included layout.

```
<include layout="@layout/modal_popup_view"
app:viewModel="@{viewModel.popupViewModel}" />
```